# get the current function name in javascript

Tags: jquery, function

I have this piece of code:

```
function MyFunction()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "foo=bar",
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(arguments.callee);
        },
        success: function(jsonObject)
        {
            //do something
        }
    });
}
```

what I want is that the alert inside de error scoope shows the function name, in this case "MyFunction" but instead what I get is the error:function.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I must be missing something. Why not just write `alert('MyFunction');`?

Comment: Why do you need to get the name of the function ? Its possible that you are approaching the problem wrong.

Comment: I want some snippet that I can use in several functions. That way I can shown an error and know in which function the error happened without hardcoding the function's name

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This -

```
var my_arguments;

function MyFunction() {
    my_arguments = arguments;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.google.com",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "foo=bar",
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(my_arguments.callee.name);
        },
        success: function(jsonObject) {
            //do something
        }
    });
}
```

is what you need.

The `arguments` inside the `error` function refers to this method's own `arguments` object. It does not refer to the MyFunction's `arguments` object. That's why you are getting `error:MyFunction`. Using a global variable in this case provides you a workaround to this problem.

Also, to get only the name of the function, you need to use `arguments.callee.name`. `arguments.callee` will give you a reference to the calling function, not a function name in string.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is `arguments.callee.name` however in your case the function in context in no longer `MyFunction` but the anonymous method declared as the error handler...

Answer (score 4):

In strict mode you can no longer reference callee (see the related discussion at [Javascript: is the arguments array deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121243/javascript-is-the-arguments-array-deprecated)) , so the answer from @Sayem is only valid if you aren't using strict mode.  In general you want to invoke strict mode because of its benefits to your code's reliability (see [@JohnResig article](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/)).

I still would like to have a way to reference the name of the current function just for the purposes of throw error messages with a context.  E.g.

throw myFunctionName() + ': invalid number of arguments';

For now I have to hard-code the function name within the throws.  I've moved code around and forgotten to update the hard-coded function names.

I've thought about a coding convention of having a THIS_FUNCTION_NAME = 'foobar' as a const defined at the head of the function, but of course that can get moved and not updated as well.

I guess as long as you have a stack trace available from the throw the point is moot.

Answer (score 4):

Time to refresh this thread by a fresh answer :)

Use **console.trace();**

> Just call console.trace() and Firebug will write a very informative
>   stack trace to the console. Not only will it tell you which functions
>   are on the stack, but it will include the value of each argument that
>   was passed to each function. You can click the functions or objects to
>   inspect them further.

**JavaScript** Example :

```
function fn1(arg1, arg2) {
    var arg3 = 'myArg3';
    fn2(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
function fn2(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    var obj = {
        attr1 : 'val1',
        attr2 : 'val2'
    };
    console.trace(obj);
}
fn1('myArg1', 'myArg2', 'myArg3');
```

**Firefox console** (version: 43.0.1) :
[image: Firefox console (version: 43.0.1)]

**Google Chrome console** (version: 47.0.2526.106 m):
[image: Google Chrome console (version: 47.0.2526.106 m)]

You can find [here](http://getfirebug.com/logging) all of logging functions that you need

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You are using `arguments` inside the scope of the error function. You need something like this if you want the `arguments` of MyFunction():

```
function MyFunction()
{
    var myfunction_arguments = arguments;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "foo=bar",
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(myfunction_arguments.callee);
        },
        success: function(jsonObject)
        {
            //do something
        }
    });
}
```

Is that what you mean?

---

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
            error:function(xhr){
              alert('Error: '+xhr.status+' '+xhr.statusText);
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
alert('MyFunction');
```

You can't do better than reliably, since that function has almost nothing to do with the error handler: The error handler can very possibly have been created in another context entirely, one enclosing `MyFunction`, or passed into it etc.

`MyFunction` doesn't call the handler so querying `arguments.*` isn't going to help.

You could inject a value into scope:

```
function MyFunction(){
   var _injectedFunctionName = arguments.callee.name;

   ...
   // inside the error handler
   alert(_injectedFunctionName);
   ...
}
```

Although that assumes that no value with the same name will collide (a reasonable assumption in many cases, and not so reasonable in others).

The fact that you want the function name is probably a good indication that you're thinking about the problem incorrectly. Maybe if you explain what you're trying to do more broadly the community can propose alternatives.