# JavaScript spread operator ... vs "arguments" array

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm learning JavaScript by following the book series "You don't know JS".

In the section about [spread operator](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md) `...`, the author mentioned

[image]

I have looked at the [MDN page on "arguments"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and did a search on the keyword `depre`, but nothing in the page mentions that the `arguments` is deprecated.

Am I missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8121309/7974050

Comment: There's nothing deprecated about `arguments`. You might want to file an issue at the Github repo.

Comment: I think someone is possibly confused by `strict mode` ... maybe

Answer (score 1):

MDN page on [Deprecated and obsolete features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features) in Function properties section says: "*The caller and arguments properties are **deprecated**, because they leak the function caller. Instead of the arguments property, you should use the arguments object inside function closures.*"

A agreed with @Bergi, you may start an issue on the GitHub to clarify this place.